# Database relationship name & best practice for it, in my laravel app

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a database schema in my laravel app. In that schema, there are **three models** - `Boss`, `Employee` & `Review`.

A **Boss can have many employees**. An **Employee can have many bosses**(we can consider bosses from previous jobs). An **Employee can Review his/her Boss**. *Boss can't Review anyone, so only Employee can review*.

**Thus**, there are these relationships -

**Employee & Boss has many-to-many relationship**

**Employee & Review has one-to-many relationship** ( one Employee can Review multiple Bosses, thus having multiple reviews from his/her side ).

As you can see **there is no direct relationship between `Boss` & `Review`**. *But, the **query is*** -

**What are the reviews for Boss 'x'?**

To answer this query in laravel, *I first thought that it had 'hasManyThrough' relationship*. *But, 'hasManyThrough' works only when Boss & Employee have 'one-to-many' relationship*. That is, when one Boss can have multiple Employee but not vice-versa.

So, my question is - Is there a relationship which is applicable in this scenario(like polymorphic etc.)? If yes, how to use it in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for that extra table with reviews.

Here's all you need - first the tables:

```
bosses: id, ...
employees: id, ...
boss_employee: id, boss_id, employee_id, review (nullable), ...
```

Then the models:

```php
// Boss model
public function employees()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Employee')->withPivot('review');
}

public function reviews()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Review');
}

// Employee model
public function bosses()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Boss')->withPivot('review');
}

public function reviews()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Review');
}

// Review model
protected $table = 'boss_employee';

public function boss() // or eg. reviewed
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Boss');
}

public function employee() // or eg. reviewer
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Employee');
}
```

Now, with this setup you can do this:

```
// get boss and his review
$boss = $employee->bosses->first();
$review = $boss->pivot->review;

// get review for given boss of an employee
$review = $employee->reviews()->where('boss_id', $bossId)->first();

// get bosses with reviews
$bosses = Boss::whereHas('reviews', function ($q) {
  $q->whereNotNull('review');
})->get();

// and so on and so forth
```

You can enhance your `Review` model by adding global scope so it returns only the rows from `boss_employee` table having `not null` review field. This would be pretty much the same as `SoftDeletingScope`, but the conditions need to be swapped - by default `whereNotNull`, instead of `whereNull` in the SoftDeletingScope.